# How can I downcast this object in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        vehicle = (car) Vehicle;
    }
}

class Vehicle {
   static void transport() {

    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    int age;
    String brand;
}
```

i understand that java implicitly upcasts, but I want to downcast this Vehicle instance and make it a Car. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't downcast a reference into something that it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downcasting doesn't change what class the object *is* — it only changes what the compiler knows at compile-time. If you have a `Vehicle` which is not a `Car` (as you do, since you instantiated it as `new Vehicle()`), then you can't downcast it; any attempt to will result in a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) at runtime.

Other than that, what you're doing wrong is that you're downcasting using `(car)` instead of `(Car)`. Java is case-sensitive.